# How to properly document hasattr() use

Tags: python

I see it's not considered pythonic to use `isinstance()`, and people suggest e.g. to use `hasattr()`.

I wonder what the best way is to document the proper use of a function that uses `hasattr()`.

Example: 
I get stock data from different websites (e.g. Yahoo Finance, Google Finance), and there are classes `GoogleFinanceData` and `YahooFinanceData` which both have a method `get_stock(date)`.
There is also a function which compares the value of two stocks:

```
def compare_stocks(stock1,stock2,date):
    if hasattr(stock1,'get_stock') and hasattr(stock2,'get_stock'):
        if stock1.get_stock(date) < stock2.get_stock(date):
            print "stock1 < stock2"
        else:
            print "stock1 > stock2"
```

The function is used like this:

```
compare_stocks(GoogleFinanceData('Microsoft'),YahooFinanceData('Apple'),'2012-03-14')
```

It is NOT used like this:

```
compare_stocks('Tree',123,'bla')
```

The question is: How do I let people know which classes they can use for `stock1` and `stock2`? Am I supposed to write a docstring like `"stock1 and stock2 ought to have a method get_stock"` and people have to look through the source themselves? Or do I put all right classes into one module and reference that file in the docstring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see whats unpythonic about the use of `isinstance()`, I would create a base class and refer to the base class' documentation.

```
def compare_stocks(stock1, stock2, date):
    """ Compares stock data of two FinanceData objects at a certain time. """
    if isinstance(stock1, FinanceData) and isinstance(stock2, FinanceData):
        return 'comparison'

class FinanceData(object):
    def get_stock(self, date):
        """ Returns stock data in format XX, expects parameter date in format YY """
        raise NotImplementedError

class GoogleFinanceData(FinanceData):
    def get_stock(self, date):
        """ Implements FinanceData.get_stock() """
        return 'important data'
```

As you see I don't use duck-typing here, but since you've asked this question in regards to documentation, I think this is the cleaner approach for readability. Whenever another developer sees the `compare_stocks` function or a `get_stock` method he knows exactly where he has to look for further information regarding functionality, data structure or implementation details.

Answer (score 4):

If all you ever do is call the function with `*FinanceData` instances, I'd not even bother with testing for the `get_stock` method; it's an error to pass in anything else and the function should just break if someone passes in strings.

In other words, just document your function as expecting a `get_stock()` method, and not test at all. Duck typing is for code that needs to accept distinctly different types of input, not for code that only works for one specific type.

Answer (score 1):

Do what you suggest, put in the docstring that passed arguments should have a get_stock function, that is what your function requires, listing classes is bad since the code may well be used with derived or other classes when it suits someone.